# Regex pattern to split verilog path in different instances using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, verilog

I have a software that parses Verilog paths and is in charge of mapping such paths to a sequence of objects. The problem is to find a regular expression to split Verilog paths in sequences of instance names.

Verilog paths are sequences of Verilog identifiers concatenated with dots. Each identifier is an instance name. The "." relationship in A.B.C means that, in the module hierarchy, A is the parent and B is one of the children of A. C is one of the children of B.

Each Verilog path identifies a unique instance in the module hierarchy.

Pseudocode:

```
Verilog Identifier A
Verilog Identifier B
Verilog Identifier C
```

Path to instance C of parent B that is child of A:

```
    A.B.C
```

Now, the issue is that Verilog identifiers can be any sequence of "*letters, digits, underscores (_) and dollar signs ($). The first character of an identifier can only be a letter or an underscore*" as stated in this page: http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00018.htm

With this situation Python would be able to split the path by just writing:

```
>>> path = "a.verilog.path"
>>> print path.split(".")
['a', 'verilog', 'path']
```

Unfortunately identifiers can be **escaped identifiers**.

Escaped identifiers start with a backslash and end with a space. Within backslash and space you can have any character (except for space), even dots!

```
\an_escaped_identifier_that_ends_with_space
\another-identifier,withsome.dots)insideit_ending_withspace
```

So things get more complicated and you cannot rely on split anymore.
Here's an example:

```
Verilog Identifier identifier1
Verilog Identifier \escaped.identifier_2 
Verilog Identifier identifier3
```

Path to instance identifier3 of parent \escaped.identifier_2 that is child of identifier1:

```
    identifier1.\escaped.identifier_2 .identifier3
```

So, how can we use Python's `re` module to address all possible Verilog paths composed of an **arbitrary** number of identifiers and/or escaped identifiers?

Comment: Based on the accepted answer i think i missed something in your question, did you just want a regex pattern that matched individual verilog identifiers or did you want some sort of solution to parse a path into individual identifiers?

Comment: Okay I see that you are now working to improve upon that answer, generally a strategy on SO is to not accept an answer unless you feel it fully answers your question, and even then to hold off for up to 24 hours. Once a question has an accepted answer most users, such as myself, are discouraged from answering the question. Its possible that the fastest answer could be pretty good, but an answer that had more time put into it ends up being better. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: I see, and I agree. So is it better to switch off the tick or keep everything as it is now?

Comment: Yes, if nobody comes along with a better answer and you are satisfied with a particular answer accept it. Unfortunately in my case, I'm now busy, maybe I'll answer later :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([a-z_][a-z0-9$_]*|\\\S* )` should match both regular and escaped identifiers.

https://regex101.com/r/IxLakb/2

Comment: It seems to be a good answer: assuming the path is a valid Verilog path it seems to work (I tested it a bit). Now I'm trying to understand the possible checks that need to be done to validate the path before parsing, but this is another question, maybe. Anyway, thumbs up!

Comment: That is a bit more complicated. I think this one works, but when a regex gets this long, it's harder to be sure. https://regex101.com/r/IxLakb/4

Comment: I think we can complete the answer by adding the full Python code and improve tests. First `import re` then execute `re.compile(r"([a-z_][a-z0-9$_]*|\\\S* )").split(s)[1:-1]` in which the [1:-1] removes empty strings at the beginning and at the end of the list. The list is now composed of identifiers and dot separators.

Comment: Any quick way to remove dots keeping the single-string command? :)

Comment: As suggested by Will Barnwell I'm editing this answer to include Python code and complete this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this is to use a regex to replace dots inside escaped strings with some special marker, such as `||`, and then split on dots as before. Afterwords if you want to dots back you can replace your special marker with dots in each identifier.

Something like:

```
import re

path="we_are_1.a_law_ab1ding_2.\path.yep.mhmmm_3 .nothing_to_s33_here_4"
dot_mask=re.compile(r'(\\[A-Za-z_|]+)\.(?=[^\s]*\s)')
masked_path=path
while( re.search(dot_mask,masked_path) != None):
  masked_path=re.sub(dot_mask,r'\g<1>||',masked_path)

masked_identifiers=masked_path.split('.')

unmask=re.compile(r'\|{2}')
unmasked_identifiers = []
for i in range(0,len(masked_identifiers)):
  unmasked_identifiers.append(re.sub(unmask,'.',masked_identifiers[i]))
```

Demo: https://repl.it/LEWa/1

Comment: I think a performance test would be useful to understand which of the approaches, yours or the regex approach, is faster.

Comment: honestly i think the approach using a regex as the split token and then cleaning `'.'` elements from the list is the more elegant solution, I just felt that this is another approach that could be considered

Comment: I just created this Gist https://gist.github.com/auserdude/e528d06ee6dd12600e01bde17f23e2c7 with a small test for the single regex approach. It can be used to do a qualitative performance comparison between Python and C++ in doing this operation. Notice that, as in Python, compilation of the regex takes a lot of time so better do it just once when the program begins.

Comment: I'm not going to run comparative tests, I believe the single regex solution is algorithmically better, but my stackoverflow answer is better.

Comment: Formally yes, I prefer this answer, but I think I'm going to use the compact regex for performance reasons.

Comment: You should create your own self-answer or edit Haken's answer and expand it and then accept